# Detecting dynamic nth div with intersectionObserver API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

I have an Infinite Scroll with `React.js`

It is literally Infinite, so I can't measure How many is it.

```
<div className="InfiniteScroll">
  <div ref={observer} className="item">item</div>
  <div ref={observer2} className="item">item</div>
  {/* Actually I am using map() */}
  {...}
</div>
```

I can add `IntersectionObserver` on any `div`.

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(() => { 
  console.log('Found it');
},{
  root: divRef.current,
  rootMargin: ...,
});
```

When I want to know the currently visible divs, How can I know that with this?

Add `IntersectionObserver` on each `div` looks not reasonable.

If I want to invoke some function with **1,000th div** or **random div**, how can I achieve it?

Comment: are you using a map to display the data?

Comment: @RamyRagab Yes I am using `map()` for array.

Answer (score 0):

you can set any div with code

```
new IntersectionObserver(function(div) {
    div.isIntersecting && do_something();
}).observe(div);
```

Comment: How can I access the 1001st div?

Comment: ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback]);
can you set IntersectionObserver inside callback ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you attach a ref to the very last div. So when that last div is intersecting, then you can invoke your function there.

**Attaching ref to the last div**

```
{list.map((item, index) => {
    if (item.length === index + 1) {
      return <div ref={lastItemElementRef} key={item}>{item}</div>
    } else {
      return <div key={item}>{item}</div>
    }
})}
```

Now when you reach this last div you can have an external API call for infinite scroll and invoke some function

**Intersecting logic**

```
  const observer = useRef()
  const lastItemElementRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (loading) return
    if (observer.current) observer.current.disconnect()
    observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        // logic for triggering set state and API call - Infinite scroll
        // some other function invokation
      }
    })
    if (node) observer.current.observe(node)
  }, [loading, otherdependencies])
```

Comment: I already use the first div and last div with `IntersectionObserver`. 
but I am struggling with `nth` div.  
When I detected `412th` div, I would like to invoke some function. 
The number could be dynamic.